# Why is the declaration/definition order still important in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

For many times now, I have had problems with the declaration and definition order in C++:

```
struct A {
    void Test() { B(); }
};

void B() {
    A a;
}
```

Of course this can be solved by predeclaring `B()`. *Usually* this is good enough to solve any of these problems. But when working with module based header-only libraries or similarily complex include systems, this declaration/definition concept can be really painful. I have included a simple example below.

Nowadays most modern language compilers do a two-pass over the source files to build the declarations in the first pass and process the definitions in the second one. Introducing this scheme into C++ shouldn't break any old code either. Therefore,

- Why hasn't this, or a similar approach, been introduced into c++ already?
- Are there any relevant clauses in the current standard inhibiting this approach?

---

### Example

This is an example of a module based header library, which has blocking includes because of missing predeclarations. To solve this, the user of the library would have to predeclare the "missing" classes, which is not feasible.
Of course this problem might be solved by using a common include header that orders all declarations before definitions, but with a two-pass this code would also work, no modification required.

`oom.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "string.h"

struct OOM {
    String message;
};
```

`string.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "array.h"

struct String {
    Array data;
};
```

`array.h`

```
#pragma once

struct Array {
    void Alloc();
};

#include "oom.h"

void Array::Alloc() { throw OOM(); }
```

`str_usage.cpp`

```
#include "string.h"
int main() {
    String str;
}
```

Comment: There's virtue to being one-pass-able, IMO. And I may be speaking out of bias, but I find code that *requires* two passes (both by a programmer and a compiler) to be harder to read.

Comment: If I find circular deps in my progs, I find typically a design problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void f(int);
void g() { f(3.14); }
void f(double);
```

`g` currently calls `f(int)`, because it's the only `f` visible. What does it call in your world?

- If it calls `f(double)`, you just broke copious existing code.
- If you came up with some rules to make it still call `f(int)`, then that means if I write

  ```
  void g2() { f2(3.14); }
  void f2(double);
  ```

  and then introduce a *worse* match for the argument - say,  `void f2(int);` before `g2`, `g2` will suddenly start calling the wrong thing. That's a maintainability nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution is to separate class definitions from function definitions:

```
struct A {
    void Test();
};

struct B {
    A a;
};

inline void A::Test() {
    B();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ambiguities in the C++ grammar that can only be resolved if you know what an identifier refers to.

For example:

```
a * b;
```

can be either a multiplication if `a` is a variable, or a pointer declaration if `a` is a type. Each of these leads to a different parse tree, so the parser must know what `a` is.

This means that parsing and name resolution cannot be performed in separate passes, but must be done in one pass, leading to the requirement to pre-declare names.

Comment: Couldn't this be solved by delaying these ambiguities until all candidates are resolved? When there are no "pending declarations" that could create a type named `a`, this is not ambiguous. I mean it's not like the user choses one of two meanings by predeclaration. The code isn't ambiguous in the first place. `a * b` is perfectly defined by the context. Yes, it can have two meanings, but the context determinits which one it is.

Comment: @nyronium No. In more modern languages, the first pass constructs an abstract syntax tree (AST) from the code, and the second pass performs name resolution. But here you can't build the AST before doing name resolution because the parser is missing information. The ambiguity shown above means that the parser won't know how to proceed with parsing the rest of the code.